# Count & Average files in a folder

Tags: powershell, foreach, directory, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

Here is my code:

```
$folders = gci C:\NuGetRoot\NugetServer -Directory
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    @{ServerName=$env:COMPUTERNAME;
        ProjectGroupID = $folder.Name;
        NuGetPackageCount = (gci $folder.FullName\Packages -Include '*.txt') | %{$_.Size}.Count;
        AverageSize = gci $folder.FullName -Recurse -Filter *.txt | measure-object -property length -average;
    } | Export-Csv -Path d:\monitoring\NugetStatistics -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

I am looping through the folders in C:\NuGetRoot\NugetServer and then displaying the server name, the folder name (ProjectGroupID), package count of files ending in .nupkg in the 'packages folder for each folder, and the avg size of all of the files that are contained within the "packages" folder for each folder. The server name and ProjectGroupID display correctly. The count and average one aren't. I get the error:

```
gci : Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name. Parameter name:
path2
At line:5 char:30
+ NuGetPackageCount = (gci $folder.FullName\packages -Include '*.nupkg') | ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (D:\apps\nuget.ciodev.accenture.com:String) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand*
```

I think it has something to do with the "\packages", because if I remove that it works, but I need to navigate to that folder because that's where the files are.

Comment: `(gci $folder.FullName\Packages -Include '*.txt')` > `(gci "$($folder.FullName)\Packages" -Include '*.txt')` Need to be sure the variable property expands properly. `$()` is a subexpression. It is trying to get the property `FullName\Packages` which does not exist. `Join-Path` would also work for this. `Join-Path $folder "packages"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running Get-ChildItem 3 times like you are, you could run it once for all *.nupkg files, group them by the project they're associated with, and the grouping objects would have most the info you want right there. Consider this alternative:

```
$BasePath = "C:\NuGetRoot\NugetServer"
$folders = gci "$BasePath\*\Packages\..\*.nupkg" -Recurse
$(foreach ($folder in $folders|group @{e={$_.fullname.split('\')[0..3] -join '\'}}) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ServerName=$env:COMPUTERNAME
        ProjectGroupID = Split-Path $folder.Name -Leaf
        NuGetPackageCount = $folder.group.Where({$_.Directory -match 'Packages'}).count
        AverageSize = $folder.Group | measure-object -property length -average | Select -Expand Average
    }
}) | Export-CSV d:\monitoring\NugetStatistics -NoType -Append
```

I did have to be a little creative on the Count line's RegEx match to make sure I only got things within the Packages folder, but it works just fine. I created a test set of files:

```
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectA\Packages\File2.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectA\Packages\File3.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectA\File1.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectA\File2.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectA\File3.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectB\Packages\File2.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectB\Packages\File3.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectB\File1.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectC\Packages\File2 - Copy.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectC\Packages\File2.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectC\Packages\File3 - Copy.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectC\Packages\File3.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectC\File1.nupkg
C:\Temp\Test\ProjectC\File3.nupkg
```

When I ran the above script against the `$BasePath` of C:\Temp\Test I got these results:

```
ServerName     ProjectGroupID NuGetPackageCount      AverageSize
----------     -------------- -----------------      -----------
MININT-BMOSR3C ProjectA                       2            161.2
MININT-BMOSR3C ProjectB                       2 155.333333333333
MININT-BMOSR3C ProjectC                       4 157.666666666667
```

I did want to point out that you run the Count against the Packages folder, but you run the AverageSize against the entire folder. You may want to add the `.Where()` statement from the Count line to the Average line if you only want files in the Packages folder for your average.

This should speed things up though since it only runs Get-ChildItem once, not once, and then 2 additional times for each folder, and it gets you the same data.